# Find tram stops in Openstreetmap data and connect them

Tags: openstreetmap

I have a openstreetmap xml data file for a city. What I want to do is extract all tram stops, connect them and display them on screen. I have already extracted all tram stops and I can display them on screen fine. Also with the connections. But some connections are missing, but I can't find why.

I am searching the xml file for the following things (reduced python code):

```
if isinstance(entity, osm.Node):
    if 'railway' in entity.tags and entity.tags['railway'] == 'tram_stop':
        # add node ...

    if 'tram' in entity.tags and entity.tags['tram'] == 'yes' and 'name' in entity.tags:
        # add node ...

    #if 'railway' in entity.tags and entity.tags['railway'] == 'switch':
    #    if 'name' in entity.tags:
    #        add node ...
    #    else:
    #        add also

    # read ways
    if isinstance(entity, osm.Way):
        if 'railway' in entity.tags and entity.tags['railway'] == 'tram':
            # add way

        if 'tram' in entity.tags and entity.tags['tram'] == 'yes' and 'name' in entity.tags:
        # add way
```

I think I missed some tags so there are gaps between some tram stops, but I can't find what I left out. I tried it with the

```
entity.tags['railway'] == 'switch'
```

but this was not the correct one. It fills no gaps just destroys the map with lines to points which makes no sense. Also the main station is not connected. Does somebody of you know if I missed some tags of nodes or ways. Or what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Railway stations are tagged as `railway=station` which is missing in your script. You should also look at other railway values and railway-related tags by reading the [railway wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Railways) and looking at [taginfo](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/railway#values).

If you still think there is something missing then just look at the map data. Either by activating the [data layer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Data_layer) at [openstreetmap.org](http://openstreetmap.org) or by using one of the [editors](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Editing#Top_three_editors). Identifying the missing parts should be rather easy with these two mechanisms.